# For mobile browser when a text field is in focus how do I "push" the text field to the top of the page instead of the default middle?

Tags: javascript, textfield

For example take a look at `google.com` on your iPhone or Android. When I tap the search text field it automatically goes straight to the top of the phone's screen, allowing maximum autocomplete list items.

Is there a neat, simple trick to do this with JS without affecting non-mobile users?

Comment: Yes, probably. Can you post your code so far?

Comment: @elclanrs other than just simple html for input, i don't really have anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('focus click', 'input',  function() {
    if($(window).width() <= 767) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('input').offset().top
        }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

Got it to work but there's a little stutter as `.animate()` fires after iPhone's own centering. Improvements welcome.